# How to add a value suffix in jQuery.knob

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-knob

I have problem with [jQuery.knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/)
I need to add a **Sufixx** to the value in the knob.

For Example: i need a Sufix **$** after the value, i just put in the value field, its displaying, but at that time the knob will not show the status.

[image: the screen shot for the issue]

it will not show the knob status. (but suffix is displaying).

here is the code:

```
<input type="text" class="ksta" value="<?php echo stat;?> $" data-width="50" />
```

without the suffix it working perfectly, help me to solve this issue.

Jsfiddle link for my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/renishar/DWvsh/19/

in the jsfiddle it work without the **$** sign, but not working with **$** sign in value.

(**$** sign may be any value or symbol)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this in a simple way,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.ksta').knob({
            'min':0,
            'max':100,
            'step': 1,
            'displayPrevious': true,
            'readOnly': true,
            'draw' : function () { $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%'); }
        });
    });
```

There is no need to change the styles and other details.....

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/renishar/DWvsh/20/

Comment: But in this way the value of the input field will be spoiled with the appendix see: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2aZTx/ and http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/2aZTx/1/

Comment: @Irvin Dominin aka Edward: in this case the value is correctly aligned within the knob, without any changes in the css of the knob... i think its better.

Comment: @ReNiShAR as you prefer (the knob css is not changed...), I don't like to have the value containig tha appendix, but it's your choice

Answer (score 4):

```
    <input type="text" class="ksta" value="51" data-width="80" data-thickness="0.2"/>


      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.ksta').knob({
                'min':0,
                'max':100,
                'step': 1,
                'readOnly': false,
                'data-linecap': 'round'
            });
            $('.ksta').each(function(e){
               $(this).val($(this).val()+'$'); 
            });     
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DWvsh/6/

Comment: tried this,,,, but this time also the knob not working.... pls check it on jsfiddle...

Comment: @ReNiShAR Also, you have left to keep the variable '$' sign infront of stat.

Comment: me value field are dynamic ?,,, but for many knobs u r solution not working.. chk above jsfidle

Comment: when scrolling inside the knob the symbol disappears,,

Answer (score 4):

Your code actually not work because `51$` is not a valid int number, so it display 0.

Since that the plugin actually not implement any prefix/suffix feature, I built a little hack so in the `draw` callback it:

- get the position of the input element on which knob is applied
- build a span and append it after the input, and copied the same styles of the input
- move the position of the new element to let it appear as a suffix

Request: https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/issues/65

Code:

```
    'draw': function () {
        if ($(this.i).siblings(".kb-suffix").length > 0) return
        var pos1 = parseInt($(this.i).css("marginLeft").replace('px', ''));
        var pos2 = parseInt($(this.i).css("marginTop").replace('px', ''));
        var $elem = $("<span>$</span>").attr("style", $(this.i).attr("style")).addClass("kb-suffix");
        $elem.insertAfter(this.i).css({
            marginLeft: (pos1 + 20) + "px",
            marginTop: (pos2 + 3) + "px",
            zIndex: -10
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ngX5p/

Comment: there is an issue in your code,.. the knob changes values when mouse scroll or drag in just the bottom of the knob....

Comment: @ReNiShAR I see the issue, it can be a zIndex issue, try the updated code

Comment: is there any way, without changing the css characteristics ?

Comment: @ReNiShAR no actually is the only way I found, the elements are absolutely positioned by the plugin, when I have time I try to fork and update or an extension

Answer (score 2):

As for version 1.2.8 of knob(current of writing), simply use format function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.ksta').knob({
                'min':0,
                'max':100,
                'step': 1,
                'readOnly': false,
                'data-linecap': 'round',
                'format': function(v){ return v + ' $';}
            });
        });
```